# Проблема при добавлении свойства к вершине графа в BGL

Tags: boost, c++

Я новичок в библиотеке boost. Решил начать изучать её с её графового раздела. Собственно я хочу задать вершине графа какое-то свойство, чтобы в дальнейшем его эксплуатировать. Так как в списке стандартных свойств я не нашёл подходящее пришлось его создавать самому. Для начала я написал новый тип-перечисление:

```
const int i = 10;
enum vertex_value_measure_t {vertex_value_measure = i};
```

Затем использовал BOOST_INSTALL_PROPERTY, задал новый тип, добавил его в описание графа и т. д.:

```
BOOST_INSTALL_PROPERTY (vertex, value_measure);
typedef property<vertex_value_measure_t, int> Vertex_value;
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, Vertex_object, Edge_object, Vertex_value> Graph_undir;
typedef property_map<Graph_undir, vertex_value_measure_t>::type Vertex_value_undir_t;
Vertex_value_undir_t vertex_value_undir;
```

После всего этого я создал новую шаблонную ф-ю, для того чтобы просмотреть св-ва вершин.

```
template <class Graph, class Vertex_name>
void vert_val(Graph& G, Vertex_name& vertexx_name)
{
CString str;

graph_property_iter_range<Graph, vertex_value_measure_t>::iterator vv, vv_end;
tie(vv, vv_end) = get_property_iter_range(G, vertex_value_measure);
str.Format(_T("блаблабла: %ld"), accumulate(vv, vv_end, 0));
((CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd())->m_wndOutputView.m_wndOutput.AddString(str);
}
```

Компилятор (VS 2010) ругается на строчку с accumulate. Причём много и громко. Большинство сообщений выглядят так:

```
error C2784: std::complex<T> std::operator +(const _Ty &,const std::complex<T> &): не удалось вывести аргумент шаблон для "const std::complex<T> &" из "boost::detail::error_property_not_found"
```

Если же вместо vertex_value_measure в get_property_iter_range подставить, допустим, vertex_name, то всё будет работать. Я не понимаю чего не хватает в задании свойства. 
Извиняюсь за такой объём, но жутко хочется разобраться, поэтому надеюсь на вашу помощь :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал не заморачиваться, и использовать вмето Property Lists, более простые и интуитивно понятные [Bundled Properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html). С помощью них мы можем просто поставить в соответствие каждой вершине и/или ребру, произвольную, определенную нами, структуру. Делается это примерно так:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

struct VertexProp {
    std::string cityName;
};

struct EdgeProp {
    double speed;
    std::string trainName;
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS,
                              boost::directedS, VertexProp, EdgeProp> Graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;

int main() {
    Graph g;
    Vertex m = add_vertex(g);
    g[m].cityName = "Moscow";
    Vertex s = add_vertex(g);
    g[s].cityName = "St. Petersburg";
    Edge e = add_edge(m, s, g).first;
    g[e].speed = 120;
    g[e].trainName = "A103";
    e = add_edge(s, m, g).first;
    g[e].speed = 127;
    g[e].trainName = "B512";
    std::cout << "Trains list:" << std::endl;
    BOOST_FOREACH(Edge e, edges(g)) {
        Vertex s = source(e, g);
        Vertex t = target(e, g);
        std::cout << "\tFrom " << g[s].cityName << " to " << g[t].cityName <<
                     " train \"" << g[e].trainName <<
                     "\" with speed " << g[e].speed << " km/h" << std::endl;
    }
}

Trains list:
    From Moscow to St. Petersburg train "A103" with speed 120 km/h
    From St. Petersburg to Moscow train "B512" with speed 127 km/h
```

Comment: Спасибо, ОГРОМНОЕ! Мне и впрямь такой метод больше нравится) Буду разбираться!

Answer (score 1):

Да, кстати, отвечая на свой же вопрос, если вы хотите всё-таки использовать Property Lists, то вам необходимо быть внимательными при добавлении новых свойств. Каждое предыдущее свойство должно быть вложено в последующее!
**Пример:**

```
enum vertex_object_t {vertex_object};
enum vertex_state_t {vertex_state};
namespace boost 
{
BOOST_INSTALL_PROPERTY (vertex, object); // вершина будет являться объектом
BOOST_INSTALL_PROPERTY (vertex, state); // для задания какого-то состояния объекта
}
typedef property<vertex_name_t, long> Vertex_name; // св-во для имени
typedef property<vertex_state_t, int, Vertex_name> Vertex_state; // св-во для состояния
typedef property<vertex_object_t, DWORD, Vertex_state> Vertex_object; // св-во объекта
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, Vertex_object, Edge_object> Graph_undir; // неориентированный граф
```

Собственно вот и вся проблема решилась :)

Comment: Блин, не могу никак привыкнуть в форматированию здесь. Вроде и ставлю 4 пробела, а ничего не получается =\

Comment: @myasnik90, просто надо оставлять пустую строку перед кодом.