# Breadth_first_search BGL

Tags: boost-bgl, g++, c++

Привет всем! имеется неориентированные невзвешенный граф...по графу хочу найти кратчайший путь между двумя вершинами...я так понимаю нужно использовать алгоритм поиск в ширину... для решение задачи я использую boost BGL...
для поиска в ширину предназначен алгоритм breadth***_first*****search, и чтобы этот алгоритм искал кратчайший путь, нужно написать класс Посетитель который унаследован от boost::default***_***bfs**____visitor ... как этот класс реализовать, чтобы показывал кратчайший путь между двумя вершинами ? пришлите пример или ссылку на какую либо статью или книгу (только не "C++ Boost Graph Library. Библиотека программиста") !

Answer (score 1):

А чем вам не угодила книга "C++ Boost Graph Library. Библиотека программиста"? Там может быть всё очень запутано на первый взгляд, но если с ней немного повозиться, то вещи становятся яснее.
Ещё, на мой взгляд, есть очень неплохая [Wiki](http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Boost/BGL) по BGL, когда-то даже пользовался ей. Так вот, в этой документации есть пример применения посетителя, унаследованного от default_dfs_visitor - BreadthFirstSearch.cpp

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>

#include <iostream>

// тот самый посетитель, который просто печатает порядок обхода вершин в графе
class custom_bfs_visitor : public boost::default_bfs_visitor
{
public:

  // печатать тут
  template < typename Vertex, typename Graph >
  void discover_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph & g) const
  {
    std::cout << u << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  typedef boost::adjacency_list < boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS > graph_t; // тип графа

  graph_t g; // сам граф

  add_edge(0, 1, g); // добавление рёбер в граф
  add_edge(0, 2, g);
  add_edge(1, 3, g);
  add_edge(0, 4, g);

  custom_bfs_visitor vis; // наш посетитель
  breadth_first_search(g, vertex(0, g), visitor(vis)); // вызов функции поиска в ширину

  // на выходе должно быть 0 1 2 4 3
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Ещё мне когда-то самому на этом форуме здорово помогли, так что можете [повникать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/76650/c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0-%D0%B2-bgl).